# typedef in C, what does this code mean

Tags: c, typedef

I started my programming in Java, and I'm new to C/C++, so this is new for me.

In one of my coding assignments I came across the following syntax:

```
typedef void function_name (void *param);
```

I looked up what typedef does, and I know what it does by definition. But not able to figure out what above statement means.

Next, this is the code that confused me more.

```
static function_name some_func;
```

Can someone throw any light on this?

Comment: Is it C or C++? Make up your mind.

Comment: its pure C, sorry for the confusion. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure we are on the same page. A typedef is a way of creating a new type that actually refers to an old type. For example the line

```
typedef int time_t;
```

creates a new type `time_t` that is just an alias for the type `int`. This is quite useful for application development because it allows us to encapsulate our types. For example, lets assume now, after 30 years, we realize that the 32-bit int type is no longer large enough to store a time value. With a good architecture, we can change that line to be:

```
typedef long long int time_t;
```

And in theory everything will be fine and dandy!

Back to the original question. The line you see is a typedef similar to this, but with some strange syntax. This strange syntax is a way of typedef'ing a *function pointer* -- what is a function pointer? A function pointer is a way of passing a function around as a value which allows the code to call a function without necessarily knowing exactly what function it is.

Back to the typedef. It is saying "create a new type `function_name` such that it is the class of functions that accept a `void*` as input and return void". So the new type `function_name` is the type given to any function that meet those requirements (return nothing, takes `void*`). It lets me write code like this:

```
typedef void function_name (void* data);

void my_function(void* data) // my_function has type function_name
{
     printf("%p\n", data);
}

void invoke_twice(function_name fn, void* data)
{
     fn(data); fn(data);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     invoke_twice(my_function, NULL); // my function _is_ a function
     // should print
     // 0x0
     // 0x0
}
```

The second statement

```
static function_name some_func;
```

Is a little puzzling to me why anyone would do this. It is a very obfuscated way of forward-declaring a function. In other words this statement is equivalent to

```
void some_func(void* data);
```

But who am i to judge other code. Without the full context it's hard to extrapolate the intent behind such design decisions.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation! :)

Answer (score 4):

These two declarations

```
typedef void function_name (void *param);

static function_name some_func;
```

are equivalent to

```
 static void some_func (void *param);
```

For declaring a single function, that is a pretty long winded approach, but the `typedef` would simplify declaring a bunch of functions of the same *shape*:

```
static function_name func1;
static function_name func2;
static function_name func3;
static function_name func4;
```

---

Whether this is a net gain in clarity of declarations is unclear.  But a more complicated function declaration could easily be helpful:

```
 typedef struct some_st **(*func) (int v, char **a, int (*kw) (int p1, int p2));
```

This declares `func` as a pointer to a function which returns an indirect pointer to a struct and the function takes 3 parameters, the last of which is a function pointer.

Comment: Thank you, this helps.. actually the {function_name}  has been used in a lot of places in the given code.